# Webpack: Can't find module after moving webpack.config.json

Tags: webpack

This is a very simple question which I can't seem to figure out.

I have a project with this configuration

```
- Folder
    - SubFolder 1
    - react
        - webpack.config.json
        - package.json
        - package-lock.json
        - node_modules
        - src
            - somecode.js
            - somecode2.js
```

I want to move the webpack to the root folder as folllows:

```
- Folder
    - SubFolder 1
    - webpack.config.json
    - react
        - package.json
        - package-lock.json
        - node_modules
        - src
            - somecode.js
            - somecode2.js
```

Is this something possible?

My webpack before moving was as follows:

```
/// <binding />
"use strict";
const path = require("path");
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require("webpack-notifier");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../Scripts/ReactScript");

const app = {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        "./src/index.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: outputPath,
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: [
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin(),
        new AssetsPlugin({
            removeFullPathAutoPrefix: true,
            fileName: 'webpack.assets.json',
            path: outputPath
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [
                path.resolve(outputPath, '*.js'),
                path.resolve(outputPath, '*.js.map')
            ],
            dangerouslyAllowCleanPatternsOutsideProject: true,
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.jsx'
        ],
    },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.output.filename = '[name].js';
}
module.exports = app;
```

I thought by only adding the context property would work `context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'react')` but it doesn't seem to work because obviously, the require's will not work properly. Can something like this be done? Should I also move package.json and package-lock.json (and snode_modules)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then when you run the webpack script, you need to specify the path to the config

```
--config [your path]
```